# Is there a clickable button to the analytics section?

Tags: support

So I got the last privilege recently, and I remember somewhere they showed me the link to the analytics section. But I dont remember it and I dont see a button to access it. Is there a clickable button to the analytics section?

Comment: Not sure if there is a clickable button, but you can visit it at [/site-analytics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) as described in [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)

Comment: I wonder why duckduckgo.com is listed as refering site and not search engine?

Comment: As for the DuckDuckGo... [Why is duckduckgo.com listed as referrer rather than search engine on analytics page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258390)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Site analytics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) is accessible from [Moderation Tools](https://anime.stackexchange.com/tools) under "Links",

> [image: Moderation Tools]

which is accessible from "Review queue" popup on the top bar, or ["Review queue" page](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review).

> [image: "Review queue" pop-up] [image: "Review queue" page]

---

Otherwise, it's also accessible from [the "Access To Site Analytics" privilege help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)